# Citrix XenDesktop - Session still active despite published application already closed on client

Tags: citrix, xendesktop

I'm using Citrix XenDesktop 7.9 on Windows Server 2019 and I'm trying to publish an application so that it opens in a seamless window on the client's computer. Everyting is working, but I'm running into the problem that after closing the published application, the session that has been created is still showing as active within Citrix Studio. On the server where Citrix is installed, I have not created any special group policies. Everything has been left as-is.

The problem occurs, when a user signs on to the Citrix Receiver's website and opens a publishesd application (I've set up notepad.exe as a simple test). The application opens in a seamless window (as it should) but after closing this window, I'd expect the application to close **and** the Citrix session to be automatically ended aswell. Instead, the session remains active, with Citrix Studio telling me "application closed, but session still active" in the session display list.

I have already tried setting the registry key for notepad.exe as described in the following support page: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX891671/graceful-logoff-from-a-published-application-renders-the-session-in-active-state but couldn't get it to work.

How can I force the closing of the Citrix session when the published application is closed on the client's computer?

I'd be thankful for any kind of advice.